# Why successful results are not appearing from search bar in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Mysqli code I have is not displaying the results of a successful search. The query is correct in terms of the statements as this was testing in MYSQL. But when trying to use mysqli, I can't seem the get the results to appear after a successful search. What am i doing wrong? I am getting no errors when doing error reporting and there is no misspelling in the query. I don't know if it's because query needs to outside the loop, or I am binding the parameters incorrectly or something like that but the code used to work in old mysql code but I can't get it working in mysqli (can't use PDO due to version of my PHP)

URL to application is [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php). If you type in "AAD", it says it can't find any results when in reality it should do because there are 5 rows in the db which contains the term 'AAD'

Below is the form code:

```
<form action="previousquestions.php" method="get">
      <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo $questioncontent; ?>" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>
```

Below is the whole mysqli code and its comments

```
//Get terms entered in the textbox    
$questioncontent = (isset($_GET['questioncontent'])) ? $_GET['questioncontent'] : '';

$searchquestion = $questioncontent;
$terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

//Start of query      
$questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, an.Answer, r.ReplyType,
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

WHERE ";

$i=0;
//loop through each term
foreach ($terms as &$each) { 
$each = '%'.$each.'%';    
$i++;         

//if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement       
if ($i == 1){         
$questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";     
} else {     
//If more than 1 term then add an OR statement    
$questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";    
} 
}  
//group terms by terms entered in chronilogical order                
$questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY "; $i = 0; foreach ($terms as $each) {     
$i++;      

//if multiple terms, then display results that contains all terms first, then start displaying other results by knocking off 1 term at a time                    
if ($i != 1)         
$questionquery .= "+";     
$questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)"; 
} 

$questionquery .= " DESC "; 

//bind the parameters by the amount of terms there are      
$types = "";
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($terms); $i++) {
$types .= "s";
}

//merge the parameters and the terms    
$eachterms = array_merge( array($types), $terms);

//prepare quert    
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery);
//in array call all the parameters and its terms      
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $eachterms);
//execute terms 
$stmt->execute();
//bind the result
$stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionContent); 


//display the results of the successful search
$output = "";
$output .= "
<table border='1' id='resulttbl'>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
</tr>
";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$output .= "
<tr>
<td class='questiontd'>{$dbQuestionContent['QuestionContent']}</td>
</tr>";
}
$output .= "        </table>";

echo $output;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error message is that `$stmt` is not a [*MySQLi_Stmt* object](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt). The reason for that is a syntax error in your statement you pass to `$mysqli->prepare`.

```
"… q.QuestionContent LIKE '%'.$each.'%' "
```

This results in something like:

```
… q.QuestionContent LIKE '%'.<value of each>.'%'
```

The issues here: `.` is not the string concatenation operator in MySQL (you would need to use `+`) and `$each` is probably not a properly quoted MySQL string declaration, so that it would result in a valid expression.

Apart from that, inserting data directly into your statement, you undermine one of the main reason to use prepared statements: to separate command and data from each other so that data cannot misinterpreted as command (i. e. SQL Injection).

So instead of inserting the string values directly, place a `?` instead. Then prepare the statement and [bind the parameters](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt.bind_param) to it for execution:

```
$questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, an.Answer, r.ReplyType,
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

WHERE ";

$paramTypes = '';
$params = array();
$i=0;
//loop through each term
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    //if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement
    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
    } else {
        //If more than 1 term then add an OR statement
        $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
    }
    $params[] = "%$each%";
    $paramTypes .= "s";
}  
//group terms by terms entered in chronilogical order                
$questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    //if multiple terms, then display results that contains all terms first, then start displaying other results by knocking off 1 term at a time
    if ($i != 1) $questionquery .= "+";
    $questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)";
    $params[] = "%$each%";
    $paramTypes .= "s"
}
$questionquery .= " DESC ";

//prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery);
//bind parameters
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_params'), array_merge(array($paramTypes), $params));
//execute query
$stmt->execute();
```

Oh, and again: You should really have a look at [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html). It can make this whole manual query building obsolete:

```
… WHERE MATCH (q.QuestionContent) AGAINST ("search terms" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Hi, Gumbo just 2 little question, where you have shown the line f code for full text search, how do I put that line of code in the query, do I put it next to the WHERE clause and then add and AND clause for the 2 lIKE statements? Also when testing your code, it is showing me a warning after submitting the search stating 
`Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'mysqli_stmt::bind_params' was given in ... on line 98`. Upvoted answer

Comment: @user1421767 I haven’t tested the query; preparing it still might fail due to a syntax error. And if you want to use fulltext search instead, read the linked page first. It will explain everything necessary.

Comment: I will read the document, but are saying replace the LIKE statements for ` MATCH (q.QuestionContent) AGAINST ("search terms" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`? Or do I still need to use the LIKE statements?

Comment: @user1421767 No, the single `MATCH … AGAINST …` would replace all your `… LIKE …` expressions.

Comment: So should my query be this: `$questionquery = "
SELECT *
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

WHERE MATCH (q.QuestionContent) AGAINST ("$each" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ";` (Using $each to match term) And then finish the query off with the group by, orderby and IF I have at end of my query

Comment: @user1421767 Yes, and you can actually use the full search term for the match, so don’t do it for each word separately. And to order the results by matching score, use the same `MATCH` expression in `ORDER BY`. But you really should read the linked chapter first.

Comment: I will read some chapters and attempt on doing this. I will get back to you some time today if I need to if I can't get it to work. If I do get it to work then I will obviously mark your answer :)

Comment: Hi, gumbo, I am receiving another fatal error while trying to do a full text search. Can you please look at my updated code and comment to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: To be honest, I read first chapter and it was well over my head lol, I gave it a go but obviously I was going down the wrong route, I will rebind the parameters and see what happens. cheers :)

Comment: I have updated code, I am now back to the first warning we commented as well as receiving a fatal error which goes with it:`Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Array' was given in ... on line 78`
AND
`Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ... on line 79` I miss old mysql code :(, but got to use mysqli now as everybody at SO says that is the future, (can't use PDO because of php version I currently have). I need to get some books on mysqli

Comment: @user1421767 Did the statement preparation succeed?

Comment: Just sent a comment above your last one stating I now have a warning and a fatal error. You can text the search bar yourself if you want by clicking on the link I provided in question but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the statements:

```
$questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE '%'.$each.'%' ,1,0)";
$questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE '%'.$each.'%' ";
$questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE '%'.$each.'%' ";
```

to this (respectively):

```
$questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE '%" . $each . "%' ,1,0)";
$questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE '%" . $each . "%' ";
$questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE '%" . $each . "%' ";
```

Also, I think you need to do this for your `$stmt` variable:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($questionquery);
//execute query
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Gumbo Isn't that how it is defined on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

Comment: @T-ShirtDude I am just test your answer n your application. I will let you know what is happening in 5 mins :)

Comment: One of the reasons for prepared statements is to separate command and data. But here you mix it up again.

Comment: @T-ShirtDude OK it has removed the fatal error but if I roll back to my previous question, it is causing the search bar to not work correctly. There is one little issue where if it is a successful search, it is not showing the results from the search, do you have any idea on this? I am updating code, give me 2 mins

Comment: I have updated code, I have not included this code: `$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();` because it removed the error without this. I did attempt that line of code in my app but it didn't change outcome it terms of showing results of the search